# FreqDist().plot() as an histogram

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I am using `NLTK` and `FreqDist().plot()` . But for curiosity, it's there a way to `transform` the `line graph` into an `histogram`? and how I can put labels in both cases?

I've searched in the documentation, but sadly it isn't detailed for it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It seems NTLK has a tabulate() method, which gives you the numeric data. From there on you could use pylab to generate the hist() function (or bar() for a bar plot).